# Add style/spacing to React Breadcrumb

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functionning breacrumb in this example https://codesandbox.io/s/bare-bones-example-kcdrt?file=/index.js. Problem is that the render displays every element in the same line without any spacing.

I would want something like this in the render : **Home > Users > John**   instead of **HomeUsersJohn**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tackle this a few different ways, in no particular order:

- Add the spacing when rendering each breadcrumb

```js
const Breadcrumbs = withBreadcrumbs()(({ breadcrumbs }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    {breadcrumbs.map(({ breadcrumb }) => <span>{breadcrumb} &gt;</span>)}
  </React.Fragment>
));
```

Key here being the rendering of the `&gt;` symbol and wrapped span tag.

- Use the CSS pseudo selectors to add the space and separator to each breadcrumb element.

```js
const Breadcrumbs = withBreadcrumbs()(({ breadcrumbs }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    {breadcrumbs.map(({ breadcrumb }) => <span className="crumb">{breadcrumb}</span>)}
  </React.Fragment>
));
```

```css
.crumb::after {
  padding-left: 0.625rem;
  content: '>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! The first one worked perfectly. Although I would prefered just the last element of the breadcrumb to not have the ">" , For now it shows something like "Home > Users > John >" instead of Home > Users > John.

Comment: My pleasure - I will show you a way of tackling that in your CodeSandbox. Give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: Basically, you flip the symbol to the beginning of each breadcrumb, instead of the end. Then use `map`'s index to determine if an element is the first one.

https://codesandbox.io/s/bare-bones-example-forked-q6x2r?file=/index.js:642-752

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I wanted. I just started learning React so it might seem noobish haha. Anyway appreciate your help sir!

Comment: With HTML, CSS and React/Javascript, there's usually several ways to tackle the same problem. Especially when it comes to how something appears on a User's screen! I am glad that I was able to help!

Comment: Yes that is noted! I'm still having a hard time trying to implement CSS in different places but i'm learning. Have a great day :)